# How to add middleware auth sanctum to API routes in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, middleware

i have a project that uses API and Web routes

web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum',config('jetstream.auth_session'),'verified'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/admindashboard', function () { return view('dashboard');})->name('dashboard');
});
```

the above is working fine and i can call `auth()->user()` inside the blade

but here in

api.php:

```
Route::prefix('orders')->as('orders.')->controller(OrderController::class)->group(function(){
Route::get('index', 'index')->name('index');
});
```

there is no middleware and i can't use `auth()->user()` inside its blade

how can i wrap the above routes (in api.php) with middleware so i can use auth in balde?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's the same middleware that you can use in apis as well.

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
  // Authenticated Routes in api.php
  Route::get('/user', function ()
    {
        return auth()->user();
    });
});
```

Comment: when i add the above i get redirect to homepage

Comment: This means you're not logged in... That's why you're redirected back.